# SQL - How to return multiple values after comparing with another table and the return value is again compared?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Need help with the above query. Basically I have table A and B.

Table A

```
+-------------+
|Paper| Stone
+-------------+
| A1  | B1 |
| A2  | B2 |
| A3  | B3 |
+-------------+
```

Table B

```
+-------------+
|Paper| Stone
+-------------+
|A1   | B1
|A1   | B3
|A1   | B1
|A2   | B2
+-------------+
```

First I need to get Table A paper and match with Table B paper to return matching stone values into table C,

But there are conditions since e.g A1 has many Stone values.

Firstly the table B's stone value that matches table A's stone value shld only be returned

Secondly if the stone value does not match then it shld be blank.

Sample table C is shown below.

```
Table C
+--------------------+
|Paper| Stone | Match
+--------------------+
|A1   |  B1 |  B1
|A2   |  B2 |  B2
|A3   |  B3 |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL? I'd try a `LEFT JOIN` from TableA to TableB btw.

Comment: looks like homework, you must attempt it, then ask specific advice if stuck

Comment: Suppose Table B has A2, B3 record. What should be returned in the second row of the result?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. For relational tables, this is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;

 CREATE TABLE Table_A
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,paper CHAR(2) NOT NULL
 ,stone CHAR(2) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO table_a (paper,stone) VALUES
 ('A1','B1'),
 ('A2','B2'),
 ('A3','B3');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;

 CREATE TABLE Table_B
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,paper CHAR(2) NOT NULL
 ,stone CHAR(2) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO table_b (paper,stone) VALUES
 ('A1','B1'),
 ('A1','B3'),
 ('A1','B1'),
 ('A2','B2');

 SELECT DISTINCT a.*
               , b.stone
            FROM table_a a
            LEFT
            JOIN table_b b
              ON b.paper = a.paper 
             AND b.stone = a.stone;

 +----+-------+-------+-------+
 | id | paper | stone | stone |
 +----+-------+-------+-------+
 |  1 | A1    | B1    | B1    |
 |  2 | A2    | B2    | B2    |
 |  3 | A3    | B3    | NULL  |
 +----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Previously i did a left outer join. and i didnt get what i wanted due to the conditions specified. Currently the table A i was referring to is actually a sql statment. I have temp created a view and then used the above query. How do i incoparate a sql statment into the above query. E.g. the sql query is table_a

Comment: I don't understand. However, in general, when imposing conditions on the right hand table of a LEFT JOIN, those conditions should be placed within the ON clause rather than the WHERE clause.

Comment: I mean could i replace table_a with a sql select statment?

Comment: you mean like this SELECT a.Paper, a.Stone, 
  CASE 
    WHEN c.Stone IS NULL 
    THEN '' 
    ELSE c.Stone 
    END `Match`
  FROM a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.Paper,a.Stone
    FROM a 
    JOIN b 
      ON a.paper=b.paper AND a.Stone=b.Stone    
) c
  ON a.paper=c.paper

Comment: Yes, something like that.